# How to show MemoryStream from WCF service in HTML-frame

Tags: html, forms, wcf, frame, memorystream

I have a webpage that looks like this:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Page</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <FRAMESET FRAMEBORDER=NO FRAMESPACING=0 COLS="17%,*">
        <FRAME MARGINWIDTH="4" MARGINHEIGHT="0" SRC="contents.htm" NAME="contents" SCROLLING=auto>
        <FRAME MARGINWIDTH="9" MARGINHEIGHT="0" SRC="body.htm" NAME="body" SCROLLING=auto>
    </FRAMESET>
</HTML>
```

The contents.htm looks like this:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
            function validate (frm)
            {
                frm.action = frm.SERVICE_URL.value;
            }
        </SCRIPT>        
    </HEAD>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="003366" text="white">
        <FORM NAME="REST" METHOD=GET ACTION="http://localhost:57233/Services/ActLifeServiceImpl.svc/D1LIV_html" onSubmit="validate(this)" target="body">
            Server (IIS)
            <SELECT NAME="SERVICE_URL" SIZE=1>
                <OPTION VALUE="http://localhost:57233/Services/ActLifeServiceImpl.svc/D1LIV_html" selected="SELECTED"> WH1212
            </SELECT>
        </FORM>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Now the WCF service called returns a MemoryStream, that is to be shown in the "body"-frame (body.htm), however that doesn't happen. Dependent of the browser used, the output is either downloaded, shown in another tab (perhaps even in another browser (Edge if IE is used)) or not shown at all. This used to work a few years ago, now it doesn't.

How can I make sure that the MemoryStream is shown in the "body"-frame?

Comment: Please share full source code you have and the complete error message you get.

Comment: Could it be that the server now returns a content-type that no longer is considered safe? I would expect the WCF service to return a application/xml content-type. I'm not sure if and where you can change that.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I tried to add this before the stream is returned:
            `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString()));`
This seems to fix it in Chrome and Firefox, however in IE/Edge the problem remains which could be a security-issue (?)